# Dotted lines in the exam class

Tags: exam, rules

I am using the `exam` document class and am using `\fillwithlines{xcm}` command to add lines. However, I want to recreate the lines as in the photograph below. Can I also make the middle two lines dotted?

```
\documentclass[20pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\fillwithlines{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your picture shows red and blue lines, not dotted lines. And could you edit your document to show a small compilable document that shows what you're doing with the `exam` class. And the `exam` class has a `\fillwithdottedlines` command. Perhaps check its [documentation](https://texdoc.org/pkg/exam)

Comment: Thank you! So, I would do \fillwithlines{1cm} \fillwithdottedlines{2cm} \fillwithlines{1cm} but the spacing is not consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** after comment.

The `\nicelines{<vertical space>}` command will create a pattern of two full lines and two dotted lines with a `vertical space` gap between the patterns.

Colors, full-line thickness, dot spacing and dot thickness are adjustable.

To change the line spacing, the environment space provided by the `setspace` package is used to change `\baselinestretch`. The example uses the value 1.5.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[20pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

%******************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{FullLinesColor}{RGB}{219,48,120} % color of the full lines  <<<<<<<<<<<
\definecolor{DottedLinesColor}{RGB}{50,120,220} % color of the dots <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Dotsep}{8pt}% dot separation <<<<<<
\newcommand{\Dotthickness}{0.5pt}% dot thickness <<<<<<
\newcommand{\LineThickness}{0.8pt}% full line thickness <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\LinesSepStretch}{1.5}% change the baseline stretch <<<<<

\newcommand{\nicelines}[1][12pt]{% \nicelines{<vertical block separation>}  
    \begin{spacing}{\LinesSepStretch}
    {\noindent\color{FullLinesColor}\rule{\linewidth}{\LineThickness}}
    {\color{DottedLinesColor}\linedotted{\linewidth}{\Dotthickness}}
    {\color{DottedLinesColor}\linedotted{\linewidth}{\Dotthickness}}
    {\vspace*{#1}\color{FullLinesColor}\rule{\linewidth}{\LineThickness}}
    \end{spacing}
}
\newcommand{\linedotted}[2]{\hbox to #1{\leaders\hbox to \Dotsep{\hss\bigpoint{#2}\hss}\hfill}} 
\newcommand{\bigpoint}[1]{\tikz\draw[DottedLinesColor,fill=DottedLinesColor] (0,0) circle (#1);}    
%********************************************************   

\begin{document}
    \nicelines[24pt]    
    \nicelines[24pt]
    \nicelines[24pt]        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this! It is perfect! I am trying to change the space between the lines and changed the \newcommand{\nicelines}[1][12pt]{% \nicelines{<vertical block separation>}  from 12pt to 10 or 8 but it is not changing anything?

Comment: @user292225 To change the space between lines use the commands provided  by he package `setspace`. Now you are using `\doublespacing` . `12pt` is the default distance between blocks of four lines, when using just `\nicelines`.

Comment: @user292225 Please see the updated answer. It was added a parameter to stretch the line separation inside the four lines block.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much- highlight appreciated. Hope you have an awesome day!